# parsing xml force array structure when there are 1 or more children

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to parse some XML which has the following structures (2 forms shown, both valid):

```
<xml-structure>
    <parent-group>
        <child>
            <element1>Some Data</element1>
            <element2>Some Data</element2>
        </child>
    </parent-group>
</xml-structure>

<xml-structure>
    <parent-group>
        <child>
            <element1>Some Data</element1>
            <element2>Some Data</element2>
        </child>
        <child>
            <element1>Some Data</element1>
            <element2>Some Data</element2>
        </child>
    </parent-group>
</xml-structure>
```

The following is used to get this entire structure into an associative array and look at the data:

```
$arr = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string($xml)),1);
$children = $arr['parent-group']['child'];
```

I want to iterate over the children to look at the data - however, the following works only if there are multiple children:

```
foreach($children as $child) {
    echo $child['element1'];
}
```

If there is only one child, then that does not work, since the following is then true:

```
$children === {'element1' => 'Some Data', 'element2' => 'Some Data'}
```

Without knowing in advance whether there are multiple children or not, how can I make sure that `$children` will always be an array (perhaps of size 1)?

Comment: Not with json_encode(). You can force an object, but you can't force an array. And in any case, since you're converting xml, all of yours "keys" are going to be strings (the tag names), which means objects are required, since arrays can only have numeric indeces.

Comment: arrays can have string indeces in PHP - the code I show above works as described for multiple children, but not when there is only a single child.

Comment: yes, but not in javascript. and that's what you're doing with json. if a key is NOT an int, it'll be made into an object. Once it's an object, you can't have json_decode turn it back into an array.

Comment: It's not in javascript - it's inside a PHP class.

Comment: This doesn't happen to me (with the first XML everything still seems to be converted properly).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following - I'd be interested if someone has a better solution:

```
$children = $arr['parent-group']['child'];
if (!empty($children['element1'])) {
    $children = array($children);
}
```

Once this was done, `$children` would always be an array of children allowing the following lines to execute properly.